# React Native & Expo - Simulators cannot make network calls and hot reload not working

Tags: react-native, expo, ios-simulator, metro-bundler

I am using Expo for developing with React Native and have been using iOS and Android simulators and to test things.

Recently, the simulators as well as any connected devices have been unable to make any network calls. The app loads fine, but no network functionality is working. It seems like it is not even attempting to make any fetch requests because the JS debugger page shows nothing in the console or network tabs. Hot reload is also not refreshing either.

When I open the app in the web browser though, everything works fine, it's still able to make fetch requests and hot reload.

From what I have looked up it seems like this is something related to Metro, but nothing I tried from any other solutions has helped so far. As far as I know, I have not changed any Expo or Metro settings or configurations since the app was last working.

I have tried:

- Restarting and uninstall/reinstall simulators
- Reverting to old working commit
- Deleting all local files in the directory and reinitializing from the last working commit
- Tried clearing caches and such with these commands:
  `watchman watch-del-all`
  `rm -rf node_modules`
  `npx expo start --localhost`
  `npm cache clean`

Tried these commands as well, but as far as I know they didn't do anything:
`rm -f ./.git/index.lock`
`npx expo r -c`
`npm start --reset-cache`

Answer (score 0):

Android applications do not call API directly. You have to setup the network config in the manifest file or set following code in your manifest file application (<Application...) tag

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

As you say you are not able to call API in both simulators. Please share the API response so we can investigate more detail.

Comment: What API do you mean? Btw, the simulators and physical device connections have been working for months until yesterday, so I think this was caused by cache or update problems.

Comment: ohk, It's mean there some different issue.